# Differences of # and the reverse of # problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

> Millie wrote a five-digit whole number on a blackboard and she also wrote it in reversed order. She considered the difference of her two numbers, and then told Lucy the last three digits of this difference. Can Lucy figure out the first two digits of the difference from this information alone or there could be more than one possibility?

This is an extremely difficult question, and I really have no idea how to solve this!

I came up with the equation $9999A+990B-990D-9999E=Z$ if $Z$ is the difference of $ABCDE$ and $EDCBA$ if $ABCDE$ is the original number! But I cannot solve for $A, B, C, D$ or $E$ with just a single statement.

I feel you can only solve this with logic (and probably computing brute force) e.g. for ### as the last three digits the beginning can be # or #. . .

Comment: Indeed, $Z = 9999(A-E) + 990(B-D)$. The information you're given is $Z \mod 1000$, and you would like to know whether you can guess $Z$ from that information. We can suppose that $ABCDE \ge EDCBA$, so you have the property that $(A-E) \in [0,9]$, and $(B-D) \in [-9,9]$...

Comment: Solving for $A,B,C,D,E$ is certainly the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @GEdgar yes, I know now :P

Comment: @HugoManet, yes, you are correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the tests for divisibility by $9$ and $11$:

- The sum of digits of the number is $\equiv\pmod 9$ to the original number
- The sum/difference of the digits of the number (units minus tens plus hundreds minus thousands plus tens of thousands etc.) is $\equiv\pmod{11}$ to the original number.

If the numbers $\overline{ABCDE}$ and $\overline{EDCBA}$ are written using digits $A, B, C, D, E$ in those two orders, then they are both $\equiv\pmod{9}$ to $A+B+C+D+E$ and they are both $\equiv\pmod{11}$ to $A-B+C-D+E$. This means that their difference is divisible by $9$ and by $11$.

Thus, if someone has provided last three digits $\overline{RST}$ of the difference $\overline{PQRST}$, then the whole difference is given by:

$$\begin{array}{rcll}\overline{PQRST}&\equiv&\overline{RST}&\pmod{1000}\\\overline{PQRST}&\equiv&0&\pmod{9}\\\overline{PQRST}&\equiv&0&\pmod{11}\end{array}$$

As per Chinese Remainder Theorem, this determines $\overline{PQRST}$ up to $\pmod{9\cdot 11\cdot 1000}$ (as $9$, $11$ and $1000$ are all coprime). As this difference is a difference of two $5$-digit numbers, it is between $0$ and $99999-10000=89999$, so being uniquely determined up to $\pmod{99000}$ means it is uniquely determined, period.

Answer: yes, knowing the last three digit of the difference, one can recover the first two digits by demanding that the whole $5$-digit difference is divisible by $9$ and $11$.

Comment: thanks! this helps me a lot :)

Comment: I know that this method works for all numbers (python proved that) but my teacher has asked whether it is possible to prove this for _all_ numbers simply without$\mod {}$?  

His question:   

`The problem would be if two different circled numbers, say x and y would have exactly the same last three digits. What would you do with these two numbers, x, y to get a nice number? What kind of properties would that number have?`  

I think he was saying whether I can prove that the two different numbers x and y do not exist.

Comment: @Arale Is your teacher possibly hinting at this: (asuming $x>y$) *make the difference* $x-y$. As both $x$ and $y$ are divisible by $9$ and $11$, $x-y$ will also be divisible by $9$ and $11$. Now, as both $x$ and $y$ has the same three last digits, the difference $x-y$ will end with $000$, i.e. will be also divisible by $1000$. Thus, it will be divisible by $9$, $11$ and $1000$ - which lets you conclude that it would be divisible by $99,000$. This means that $x-y\ge 99,000$ so $x\ge 99,000$, which we have seen is impossible.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! I was thinking about this for 8 days and this makes sense, FINALLY! Thanks again! （⊙ω⊙）